# Using sparse matrix instead of numpy distance matrix

Tags: python-3.x, sparse-matrix, distance-matrix

I have a list of car ids and a list of x,y coordinates.
I want to calculate the distance between each of the coordinates.

The problem is ,after trying for weeks now, the distance matrix has limits and I'm dealing with Gigas of files with a resulting matrix of millions of rows and columns.
Can this be done using sparse to make it more effecient?

```
list_coordinates = []
for line in coordinates.readlines():
    list_coordinates.append(line.strip().split(','))

list_coordinates_int = [list(map(float, x)) for x in list_coordinates]

list_car_id = []
for line in car_ids.readlines():
    list_car_id.append(line.strip().split(' '))

df = pd.DataFrame(list_coordinates_int, columns=['xcord', 'ycord'], index=list_car_id)

df2=pd.DataFrame(distance_matrix(df.values, df.values), index=df.index, columns=df.index)

list_coordinates : [['875.88', '588.26'], ['751.49', '656.55']]     
list_coordinates_int : [[875.88, 588.26], [751.49, 656.55]]    
list_car_id : [['car.0', 'car2.0', 'car.0', 'car2.0', 'car.0']]
```

the resulting **df2** is like this:

```
              car.0      car2.0       car.4                  
   car.0     0.000000  141.902770    0.702140            
   car2.0   141.902770    0.000000  141.205831   
   car.4    141.902770    0.702140   0.000000
```

is there a way i could get the same df2 using sparse or any other mehtod than distance matrix?

Comment: what is `coordinates`? Based on it, you can remove two for-loops, which will save a lot of time.

Comment: What is "list_coordinates_int"? Does each car have two coordinates associated with it? Do you want to calculate the pair-wise distances between the cars? Please elaborate using a simple example as to what the input could be and what the corresponding output should be.

Comment: Hello all, I just added some more details hoping you get the idea